# Labeling vertex to create minimum cost

Tags: algorithm, dynamic

I have this problem:

you are given a rooted tree T, representing the company hierarchy, and
you want to label each node in T with an integer 1, 2, or 3, so that every node has a
different label from its parent. The cost of an labeling is the number of nodes that have
smaller labels than their parents. Describe and analyze an algorithm to compute the
minimum cost of any labeling of the given tree T.

How can I solve this problem using **dynamic programming**?

Comment: Tree is binary, right?

Comment: not necessarily

Comment: Where did you get stuck? There's a natural way to apply DP to trees (since subtrees are smaller problems that can be solved separately) -- so perhaps that should be your first line of attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sergey has the right idea, but since this is a general tree, there is some subtlety here in the combining step, which should avoid an exponential blowup.

Let's represent trees using the following data structure.

```
data Tree = Node | Edge Tree Tree
```

In English, a tree is either a single node, or a subtree whose root is the child of the overall root and the rest of the tree. For example, the tree

```
  *
 /|\
* * *
  |
  *
```

is represented as `Edge Node (Edge (Edge Node Node) (Edge Node Node))`.

Now, let's define a recursive procedure `dp'` that takes a tree and returns the cost of a coloring in three scenarios: root is 1, root is 2, and root is 3.

```
dp' :: Tree -> (Int, Int, Int)
dp' Node = (0, 0, 0)
dp' (Edge a b) = let
    (a1, a2, a3) = dp' a
    (b1, b2, b3) = dp' b in
    (min               (a2     + b1) (a3 + b1)
    ,min (a1 + 1 + b2)               (a3 + b2)
    ,min (a1 + 1 + b3) (a2 + 1 + b3)
    )
```

The value `(a1 + 1 + b2)`, for example, represents the cost of setting `root(a) -> 1` and `root(b) -> 2`, incurring an additional cost of `1` because `root(a)`'s value is less than `root(b)`'s value, and `root(a)`'s parent is `root(b)`.

The overall answer is

```
dp :: Tree -> Int
dp a = let (a1, a2, a3) = dp' a in min (min a1 a2) a3
```

Comment: What should I do with the leaves of the tree? I understand I can find the solution recursively but how do I stop?

Comment: @Rotem The relevant line is `dp' Node = (0, 0, 0)`; the leaves by themselves incur no cost for any color.

Comment: Can I define it this way? (recursively) -> Cost(node, value) = sum of min(Cost(node.child,value')) for all the children of the node + counter (if value'<value counter++). For the leaves - return 0. It means: the min sum of costs for all the children of the node.

Comment: What is the time complexity?

Comment: @Rotem It's linear.

Comment: O(n)? For each node we check all of its children and take the minimum value of each one, isn't is O(n^2)?

Answer (score 0):

For each node `i` you need to calculate minimum cost of labeling of its sub-tree, assuming current node `i` has label `1`, `2`, or `3`. 
Knowing those values for each of sub-nodes of the current node, you can calculate these values for the current node.

You can implement it using `Depth-first search` kind of algo.

Comment: How can I do it recursively? I thought about defining Cost(node,value) to be = min ( sum of Cost(node.child, value') for all childs) but then I didn't know what is the stopping condition.

Comment: If node does not have child nodes it means it is a leaf and you should stop recursion. This is part of normal DFS implementation.